# Insertion Sort in Java, not able to add second item?

Tags: java

```
public class OrderedArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>> {

/** This is an array of Objects of type T */
private T[] array;
private int numItems = 0;
private int itemsRemoved=0;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
/**
 * Construct an OrderedArrayList with 10 empty slots. Note the recipe for 
 * creating an array with the generic type. You'll want to reuse this 
 * recipe in the insert() method.  You'll also possibly want to tweak this 
 * constructor a bit if you add other instance variables.
 */
public OrderedArrayList() {
    array = (T[]) new Comparable[10];

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
/**
 * _Part 1: Implement this method._
 * 
 * Inserts a new item in the OrderedArrayList. This method should ensure
 * that the list can hold the new item, and grow the backing array if
 * necessary. If the backing array must grow to accommodate the new item, it
 * should grow by a factor of 2. The new item should be placed in sorted
 * order using insertion sort. Note that the new item should be placed
 * *after* any other equivalent items that are already in the list.
 * 
 * @return the index at which the item was placed.
 */
public int insert(T item) {
    if (numItems==0){
        array[0]=item;
        numItems++;
        return 0;
    }
    if (numItems==array.length){
        T[] newArray = (T[]) new Comparable[array.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        array=newArray;
    }
    numItems++;
    for (int j = numItems-1; j >= 0; j--) {

        if (array[j].compareTo(item) <= 0){
            array[j+1] = item;
            return j+1;
        }

        else{
            array[j+1] = array[j];

        }


    }
    return -1;
}
```

When I'm trying to test this with the given tests for the assignment this method if having trouble adding in the second item

```
    @Test
public void removeWithTwoDifferentItems() {
    int i;
    OrderedArrayList<String> a = new OrderedArrayList<String>();
    a.insert("Hello!");
    a.insert("Zeno.");
    i = a.find("Hello!");
    assertEquals("Can't properly find the only string that should be in the list!", 0, i );
    i = a.remove("Hel"+"lo!");
    assertEquals("remove() expecting 1, but got something else", 1, i );
}
```

Above is the test, and it says there's an error at the insert Zeno. 
It seems like I've written this correctly but I'm not sure how to fix it?
Also if the array is full the array is supposed to grow to 20, i'm not sure if that's wrong too but i'm mainly concerned about the inserting the second thing in to the array.

Comment: "and it says there's an error at the insert Zeno" <tap> <tap> My psychic helmet doesn't seem to be working today. Perhaps you could assist by telling us (by that I mean anyone else with a broken psychic helmet) what the error is?

Comment: can you give stacktrace of the error

Comment: @RaviKumar I have no clue how to do that x_x sorry, I'm really new to programming

Comment: are you using any ide then you can see exception in console or if you are running it through command line then you can copy the exception trace from cmd.

Comment: @RaviKumar It lets me know where in the test class and the class the methods are in where it has trouble, *if (array[j].compareTo(item) <= 0){* is where is has trouble in the method class, and the test class it has trouble at the Zeno.

Comment: @RaviKumar Not sure if this is what you mean? java.lang.NullPointerException
 at OrderedArrayList.insert(OrderedArrayList.java:54)
 at OrderedArrayListTests.removeWithTwoDifferentItems(OrderedArrayListTests.java:43)

Comment: yes this is the stack trace and answer given by @Warren Dev solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Normally the items currently in the array are distributed between `array[0]` and `array[numItems - 1]`, inclusive, with the rest of the array values `null`.  However, immediately after `numItems++` just before the `for` loop, the items in the array are distributed between `array[0]` and `array[numItems - 2]`, since the new `array[numItems - 1]` still contains the `null` value it had before the increment.  As a result, when you reach the subsequent `if` statement, the first value of `array[j]` which is the same as `array[numItems - 1]`, is still `null`, and trying to call `compareTo` on `null` results in a `NullPointerException`, which is the error you're seeing.

I'd suggest moving the `numItems++` statement to after the `for` loop.